# Compiling with unordered_map fails with Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.3

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, templates, c++11

I am attempting to compile a project which was originally using tr1/unordered_map. I have removed all the references to the tr1 namespace and am now just using unordered_map (e.g. `#include <tr1/unordered_map>` becomes `#include <unordered_map>`). However, I am getting a compilation error. Upon configuration:

```
CXXR is now configured for x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /Library/Frameworks
  C compiler:                gcc  -g -O2 -fexceptions
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2
  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2 -Wno-attributes -std=c++11
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:            gcc -g -O2 -fobjc-exceptions
  Interfaces supported:      X11, aqua, tcltk
  External libraries:        readline, ICU
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, TIFF, NLS
  CR Options enabled:        framework, shared BLAS, R profiling
  CXXR Options enabled:      
  Recommended packages:      yes
```

When I attempt to compile the project I am faced with the error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/unordered_map:724:5: error: static_assert failed "Invalid allocator::value_type"
    static_assert((is_same<value_type, typename allocator_type::value_type>::value),
Environment.cpp:104:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::unordered_map<const CXXR::Symbol *, CXXR::Frame::Binding *, std::__1::hash<const CXXR::Symbol *>,
      std::__1::equal_to<const CXXR::Symbol *>, CXXR::Allocator<std::__1::pair<const CXXR::Symbol *, CXXR::Frame::Binding *> > >' requested here
    delete s_search_path_cache;
```

`s_search_path_cache` is defined as:

```
typedef
std::unordered_map<const Symbol*, Frame::Binding*,
    std::hash<const Symbol*>,
    std::equal_to<const Symbol*>,
    CXXR::Allocator<std::pair<const Symbol*, Frame::Binding*> >
    > Cache;

static Cache* s_search_path_cache;
```

I was able to find a bug report to Apache OpenOffice for a similar problem (https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=124422) but have been unable to use this to solve my issue. If anyone has any ideas I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a pesky `const` in your allocator (the second one):

```
CXXR::Allocator<std::pair<const Symbol* const, Frame::Binding*> >
```

Comment: Pesky little `const` :). Thanks Howard, this seems to have fixed the issue. In addition it looks like I'm able to get away with `typedef std::unordered_map<const Symbol*, Frame::Binding*> Cache;`